# MudBlazor DataGrid not rendering items

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, mudblazor

I am trying to use [MudBlazor's DataGrid](https://mudblazor.com/components/datagrid#default-data-grid).

This code works on [their TryMudBlazor webpage](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/wEwdEoEyBHQsZHTo), but it doesn't work when running as Blazor Server locally.

```html
<p>Before</p>

<MudDataGrid Items="@Elements">
    <Columns>
        <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.Name"/>
    </Columns>
</MudDataGrid>

<p>After</p>

@code {
    private IEnumerable<Element> Elements = new List<Element>();
    
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        Elements = new List<Element>
        {
            new Element { Name = "Test 1" },
            new Element { Name = "Test 2" },
            new Element { Name = "Test 3" }
        };
    }

    public class Element
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Any pointers why it's not rendering locally?

Comment: Define "doesnt work", errors? Exceptions? What does your browser console say? Tried your debugger? Lots of information missing here.

Comment: Doesn't work as in nothing gets rendered on-screen.

Browser console had no errors. No exceptions/errors raised.

I've just retried this and it's working now. Not sure why. Will work it out and update this if I find the answer on what I was doing wrong.

Comment: @mxmissile see self answer. Cheers for trying to help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [dotnet templates](https://mudblazor.com/getting-started/installation#using-our-dotnet-templates) offered by MudBlazor use the MudBlazor nuget package v6.0.13 and after upgrading to the latest 6.2.0, the component now renders.